# Custom ActionBar NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Sorry for my english. I have TabActivity and I want create custom action bar, but have this error:

> 04-25 20:11:17.777: E/AndroidRuntime(8083):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.bonsitelazyl/com.example.bonsitelazyl.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.bonsitelazyl/com.example.bonsitelazyl.News}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    TabHost tabHost;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabHost = getTabHost();  
        setTabs();
    } 

    private void setTabs() 
    { 
        addTab("", R.drawable.tab_news, News.class); 
        addTab("", R.drawable.tab_servises, News.class);
        addTab("", R.drawable.tab_profile, News.class);
        addTab("", R.drawable.tab_contacts, News.class);
    }

    private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
    { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(labelId);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon); 
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);      
        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

News

```
public class News extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_n);

        ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**UPD**

All log cat

> 04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.bonsitelazyl/com.example.bonsitelazyl.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.bonsitelazyl/com.example.bonsitelazyl.News}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 04-25 20:33:15.186:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 04-25 20:33:15.186:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-25 20:33:15.186:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-25 20:33:15.186:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12242): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable
>   to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.bonsitelazyl/com.example.bonsitelazyl.News}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 04-25 20:33:15.186:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1917)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:682)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at
>   android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236) 04-25 20:33:15.186:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   com.example.bonsitelazyl.MainActivity.addTab(MainActivity.java:47)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   com.example.bonsitelazyl.MainActivity.setTabs(MainActivity.java:29)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   com.example.bonsitelazyl.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  ... 11 more 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 04-25 20:33:15.186:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   com.example.bonsitelazyl.News.onCreate(News.java:15) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)

**UPD:**

**getActionBar** return null

upd:

i try android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity in new i update, i add this code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); 
        View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav);
```

> 04-25 21:09:09.550: E/AndroidRuntime(22075): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.bonsitelazyl/com.example.bonsitelazyl.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.bonsitelazyl/com.example.bonsitelazyl.News}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Post your full Log cat.

Comment: Try to extend android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity instead of Activity

Comment: @GiorgosOikonomou i have null pointer exception. I update questions

Answer (score 0):

The TabActivity is deprecated class. To add tabs to your class use the code above.

MainActivity2Activity.java

```
import java.util.Locale;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
public class MainActivity2Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity2, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

layout/activity_main_activity2.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                   android:id="@+id/pager"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                   tools:context="georgeoikonomou.fishinggps.MainActivity2Activity"/>
```

layout/fragment_main_activity2.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="georgeoikonomou.fishinggps.MainActivity2Activity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Giorgos Oikonomou have metioned  `TabActivity` is deprecated class, so I suggest you to use [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-SlidingTabLayout) way for implementing tab in your app.

You have some problems with the custom `actionBar`.

The way to use custom `ActionBar` is as describe below :

1 - Create your custom layout fot the `Actionbar`.

2 - Add the following  lines in `OnCreate` method :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
```

(If you are not using support library change this :  `getSupportActionBar()` to this :  `getActionBar()`)

Now, to get the items from the `actionBar` do like this :

(I assume you have in the action bar `TextView` named `action_bar_title` that uses as its title)

```
TextView tv =  (TextView) getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
```